# Is it possible to build type-driven function lookup tables in Scala?

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I know how to do this in Lisp / Scheme / Racket, but not in Scala.

```
// inputType  derives from In  and could be of subtype In1, In2, In3, ...
// outputType derives from Out and could be of subtype Out1, Out2, Out3, ...

def invokeTheRightFunction
  (functionName: Mystery1, inputData: [subtype of In], outputType: Mystery2): Mystery3 =
{
  val lookupTable =
    List( Mystery4(functionName1, inputType1, outputType1),
          Mystery4(functionName2, inputType2, outputType2),
          ...
          Mystery4(functionNameN, inputTypeN, outputTypeN) )
  ...Mystery5...
}
```

Based on values of `functionName`, `inputType`, and `outputType`, given `inputData` that is of a particular subtype of `In`, is it possible to use build a lookupTable so that the proper function is called with the `inputData`, and the returned value from the function with the lookupTable has the correct subtype of `Out`?

If you're wondering why I don't just use `match/case`, it's because I want there to be some generic [database handling] code in a library, but the code that uses the library will know what all the types should be going in and coming out.

The code for `In`, `Out`, and the "Mysteries" would be in the library.

Subtypes of `In` and `Out` and `lookupTable` would be in the code that uses the library.

To make this a little more concrete, let's say I have [database] stored procedures `A`, `B`, `C`.  I currently put the inputs to those stored procedures in case classes called `ArgsA`, `ArgsB`, `ArgsC`.  I get the answers back as a sequence of `RowA`, `RowB`, `RowC`. I want all or most of the error handling to happen in the library.

The code I have now has some duplication of type-specification, and I'm trying to consolidate specification of types to a single lookup table to reduce the chance of error.

Comment: What about using **typeclasses** to model this _"look-up"_?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thank you, that sounds like a great potential solution. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is very easy to achieve using a variant of a pattern called [magnet](https://kubuszok.com/2018/implicits-type-classes-and-extension-methods-part-3/#magnet-pattern). First let's define some types:

```
sealed trait In

case class In1() extends In
case class In2() extends In

sealed trait Out //Mystery2

case class Out1() extends Out
case class Out2() extends Out

sealed trait Name //Mystery1

case class Name1() extends Name
case class Name2() extends Name

sealed trait Row //Mystery3

case class Row1() extends Row
case class Row2() extends Row
```

Then we can prepare our `Magnet` typeclass:

```
sealed trait Magnet[N <: Name, I <: Int, O <: Out] {
   type Result <: Row

   def apply(name: N, in: I, out: O): Result
}
```

Inside of companion object of `Magnet` you can add entries to *"lookup"* as implicit values:

```
import scala.languageFeature.implicitConversions //you can also enable implicit conversions in build.sbt

object Magnet {

  implicit val function1 = new Magnet[Name1, In1, Out2] {
     override type Result = Row1

     override def apply(name: Name1, in: In1, out:Out2): Row1 = ???
  }

  implicit val function2 = new Magnet[Name2, In2, Out1] {
     override type Result = Row2

     override def apply(name: Name2, in: In2, out: Out1): Row2 = ???
  }

}
```

Finally, we can prepare `invokeTheRightFunction` function, which will require implicitly `Magnet`:

```
def invokeTheRightFunction[N <: Name, I <: Int, O <: Out](name: N, in: I, out: O)(implicit magnet: Magnet[N,I,O]): magnet.Result = magnet(name, in, out)
```

Let's test it out:

```
val r1: Row1 = invokeTheRightFunction(Name1(), In1(), Out2())

val r2: Row2 = invokeTheRightFunction(Name2(), In2(), Out1())
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'll check that out, and if it works, well I'll thank you again! End of the work day here, so I'll check it out when I get home in a few hours. Thanks again. I never knew about magnet! What I had before was close to what you've written, but without the missing magnet piece.